# How to edit Google Map styling in wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

I managed to grab a code from Google which allows me to edit the colors of Google Map and I have it in my code pen [here](https://codepen.io/melodiacapoeira/pen/oVorxz)

At the moment, the theme I have works in the following way: if I click under a city name, it opens the respective page and then Google map shows that particular location, and so on.

How do I implement the code I have in my pen into the WordPress site?

In the child theme, I copied the footer content and added all the script and the full footer looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer
 *
 * Contains the closing of the #content div and all content after.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package siber
 */
?>          
            <?php if(siber_styles()['footer'] == 'show' && siber_styles()['footer_scroll_top'] == 'show' && siber_styles()['header_style'] != 'side') { ?>
                <div class="scroll-top multimedia-element-set-icons-up-arrow-2" id="scroll-top"></div>
            <?php } if(siber_styles()['footer'] == 'show' || siber_styles()['footer'] == 'minified') { ?>
                <footer class="site-footer light main-row">
                    <?php if(siber_styles()['footer'] != 'minified') { ?>
                        <div class="footer-wrap">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-<?php echo esc_attr(siber_styles()['footer_col_1']) ?>">
                                        <div class="logo"><a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')) ?>"><?php echo wp_kses(siber_styles()['logo_content'], 'post') ?></a></div>
                                        <?php if(is_active_sidebar('footer-1')) { ?>
                                            <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer-1'); ?>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php if(is_active_sidebar('footer-2')) { ?>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-<?php echo esc_attr(siber_styles()['footer_col_2']) ?>">
                                        <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer-2'); ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php } if(is_active_sidebar('footer-3')) { ?>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-<?php echo esc_attr(siber_styles()['footer_col_3']) ?>">
                                        <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer-3'); ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php } if(is_active_sidebar('footer-4')) { ?>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-<?php echo esc_attr(siber_styles()['footer_col_4']) ?>">
                                        <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer-4'); ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </footer>

            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <script>
      function initMap() {

        // Create a new StyledMapType object, passing it an array of styles,
        // and the name to be displayed on the map type control.
        var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
          [
            {elementType: 'geometry', stylers: [{color: '#ebe3cd'}]},
            {elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#523735'}]},
            {elementType: 'labels.text.stroke', stylers: [{color: '#f5f1e6'}]},
            {
              featureType: 'administrative',
              elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
              stylers: [{color: '#c9b2a6'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'administrative.land_parcel',
              elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
              stylers: [{color: '#dcd2be'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'administrative.land_parcel',
              elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
              stylers: [{color: '#ae9e90'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'landscape.natural',
              elementType: 'geometry',
              stylers: [{color: '#dfd2ae'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'poi',
              elementType: 'geometry',
              stylers: [{color: '#dfd2ae'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'poi',
              elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
              stylers: [{color: '#93817c'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'poi.park',
              elementType: 'geometry.fill',
              stylers: [{color: '#a5b076'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'poi.park',
              elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
              stylers: [{color: '#447530'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'road',
              elementType: 'geometry',
              stylers: [{color: '#f5f1e6'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'road.arterial',
              elementType: 'geometry',
              stylers: [{color: '#fdfcf8'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'road.highway',
              elementType: 'geometry',
              stylers: [{color: '#f8c967'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'road.highway',
              elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
              stylers: [{color: '#e9bc62'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'road.highway.controlled_access',
              elementType: 'geometry',
              stylers: [{color: '#e98d58'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'road.highway.controlled_access',
              elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
              stylers: [{color: '#db8555'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'road.local',
              elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
              stylers: [{color: '#806b63'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'transit.line',
              elementType: 'geometry',
              stylers: [{color: '#dfd2ae'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'transit.line',
              elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
              stylers: [{color: '#8f7d77'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'transit.line',
              elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
              stylers: [{color: '#ebe3cd'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'transit.station',
              elementType: 'geometry',
              stylers: [{color: '#dfd2ae'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'water',
              elementType: 'geometry.fill',
              stylers: [{color: '#b9d3c2'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'water',
              elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
              stylers: [{color: '#92998d'}]
            }
          ],
          {name: 'Styled Map'});

        // Create a map object, and include the MapTypeId to add
        // to the map type control.
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 55.647, lng: 37.581},
          zoom: 11,
          mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: ['roadmap', 'satellite', 'hybrid', 'terrain',
                         'styled_map']
          }
        });

        //Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
        map.mapTypes.set('styled_map', styledMapType);
        map.setMapTypeId('styled_map');
      }
    </script>
        <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>

        <?php wp_footer(); ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

When I load the page, I see the following error in the console:

> You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.

If I remove the API KEY directly from the theme options, the map does not show.

Comment: Where is the other place the API is being included?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: (Editing note: there is no need to add "thanks in advance" and "hope someone can help" to your questions. We prefer technical writing here).

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain that the google maps script is included only once? I suspect that you're loading the script twice, as the error is quite clear: you're initiating google maps multiple times, but in your code above, it's only included once. 
It might be that another plugin loads the script elsewhere in your code.

Can you provide a link to the actual page?

Comment: I am having a heck of a time disabling google maps from the jobify-theme. 
I have followed the instructions from the documentation page on adding: 
but the site still fetches the google-data: in other words, the site still pulls the data from google - see the results:
 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/412666/remove-google-maps-completely-from-the-wordpress-site